# How to use const values ​from JavaScript as an argument of Django Custom template tags and filters?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

**If I have custom filters and write {% load file_name %} into index.html, How to write:**

```
<script>
    const x = 10;
    const y = "{{ obj|function:x }}";
</script>
```

Comment: If I write as const y = "{{obj | function: 'some_text'}}", it can work correctly. But if put as a variable it will be an error

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, because the expression `{{ obj|function:x }}` is parsed by Django on the server before the javascript is run by the browser, so Django can't access the javascript variable `x`. You can verify this yourself by looking at the page's HTML response in your browser's network tab
-- you will see that any template expression enclosed in `{{` `}}` is replaced by whatever value it resolves to.

If you need to use a javascript variable in Django, an alternative could be to send the variable's value to a Django view on your server and run the function there. Then you can do any computation involving that value on the server and return the appropriate response to the browser to be displayed.